# Google Sheets: Forms edit with multiple questions fix duplicate answers

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a form that has a Question that depending upon an answer will direct you to futher questions. The problem is, once you submit the form and then go back and edit your answer, if you choose another answer for the first question and it redirects to a new question because your first answer was different, the response in Google Sheets keeps both answers. How can I fix this so that it only shows the last answers? For example. When I first answer the question, I choose Option 1.

[image]

Then when I choose next I get these options.
[image]

Which once I submit will give the following response submission in Sheets.
[image]
Ok, so then if I go back and Edit my response like so...
[image]
It will redirect to a different question based on my first choice.
[image]
However, once I submit my final answer, this is what the subission looks like in Sheets.
[image]
The problem is, Column C and D answers are no longer relevant based upon the answer in Column B. How can I fix this so that Column C and D are blank as they should be and I only get the answer that is correct based upon the submission in Forms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) in your Google Sheets with a [Form Submit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#application_triggers).

### Sample Code:

```
function formSubmission(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  Logger.log(e.values);
  var data = e.values;
  var row = e.range.rowStart;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  if(data[1]=="Option 1"){
    //Remove data under Follow-up Question2 and Amount 2 (Column E and F)
    sheet.getRange(row,5,1,2).clearContent();
  }else if(data[1]=="Option 2"){
    //Remove data under Follow-up Question1 and Amount 1 (Column C and D)
    sheet.getRange(row,3,1,2).clearContent();
  }
}
```

### Pre-requisite:

[image]

[image]

### What it does?

1. Get the form submitted values using [Sheets form submit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) `values`
2. Get the form submitted target row using `range.rowStart`
3. Get the active spreadsheet and sheet with the name `Form Responses 1`
4. Check the Option selected and delete specific columns depending on the option selected.

### Output:

[image]

Comment: This works for the answers that were changed, but it removes any answer that wasn't changed. For instance, if you go back and edit your last response and don't change Option 2 and just change Option 2A to Option 2B then it leaves the "Some Question" column empty.

Comment: But can your form go to the section follow-up 2 without selecting option 2 in Some Question?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/16NWjNqsYnK2rhI3Ax8Erc66VzEtwVjFyISBrqgn3Hr4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Here's the Sheet too: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10fNJpK7IzycNjEtQPoxQ_HkHpWL72bGLHi0cq2d64R0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I updated the answer. I wasn't able to open the sample sheet since it was not shared publicly. I just tried to replicate it on my side. Please let me know if you still encountered any issues

Comment: Glad to hear that. By the way, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Ok. So... can I use this on another Sheet and Form that has more options?

Comment: Yes, you just need to add an if condition for each options. and delete specific column using [Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns).clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Comment: I see. No way to make that dynamic I suppose? In case the form adds or removes questions?

Comment: I guess it might be possible but will be complicated and it will also depend on your sample data

Comment: Ok here's my real world situation:

Question "Choose One" in Column E has options "Debit" or "Credit", If "Debit" then Amount is entered in Column F, if "Credit" then Amount is entered in Column G. I'm runninig into a situation where you can go back and edit the submission and switch it from Debit to Credit and have two Amounts entered. There are also 15 Columns (I thru W) "Subcategories" that have answers that can be changed based upon if you submit a different "Category" in H. I can't post a new image, but I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You can manipulate the columns as what I have done in the sample code. Just keep in mind that if you get the row values using `var data = e.values;` it will return an array of values based on your sheet column arrangement. You can check the value of a specific row just by using its 0-based index example Column E will be in `data[4]`. While keep in mind that if you are selecting range in the sheet using `getRange()` it uses the column number starting from 1. `Column F` is equivalent to 6 and so on..

Comment: Ok. I got it! Thanks for your help! It's hardcoded so I hope I never have to change anything! :)

Comment: No problem. If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I finally was able to do what I needed Ron M's help:

```
function formSubmission(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  Logger.log(e.values);
  var data = e.values;
  var row = e.range.rowStart;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  if(data[4]=="Debit"){
    sheet.getRange(row,7,1,1).clearContent();
  }else if(data[4]=="Credit"){
    sheet.getRange(row,6,1,1).clearContent();
  }
  if(data[7]=="INCOME"){
    sheet.getRange(row,10,1,14).clearContent();
  }else if(data[7]=="HOME"){
    sheet.getRange(row,9,1,1).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(row,11,1,13).clearContent();
  }else if(data[7]=="LIVING"){
    sheet.getRange(row,9,1,2).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(row,12,1,12).clearContent();
  }else if(data[7]=="TRANSPORTATION"){
    sheet.getRange(row,9,1,3).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(row,13,1,11).clearContent();
  }else if(data[7]=="HEALTH"){
    sheet.getRange(row,9,1,4).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(row,14,1,10).clearContent();
  }else if(data[7]=="INSURANCE"){
    sheet.getRange(row,9,1,5).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(row,15,1,9).clearContent();
  }else if(data[7]=="EDUCATION"){
    sheet.getRange(row,9,1,6).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(row,16,1,8).clearContent();
  }else if(data[7]=="CHARITY/GIFTS"){
    sheet.getRange(row,9,1,7).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(row,17,1,7).clearContent();
  }else if(data[7]=="SAVINGS"){
    sheet.getRange(row,9,1,8).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(row,18,1,6).clearContent();
  }else if(data[7]=="OBLIGATIONS"){
    sheet.getRange(row,9,1,9).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(row,19,1,5).clearContent();
  }else if(data[7]=="ENTERTAINMENT"){
    sheet.getRange(row,9,1,10).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(row,20,1,4).clearContent();
  }else if(data[7]=="PETS"){
    sheet.getRange(row,9,1,11).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(row,21,1,3).clearContent();
  }else if(data[7]=="SUBSCRIPTIONS"){
    sheet.getRange(row,9,1,12).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(row,22,1,2).clearContent();
  }else if(data[7]=="VACATION"){
    sheet.getRange(row,9,1,13).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(row,23,1,1).clearContent();
  }else if(data[7]=="MISCELLANEOUS"){
    sheet.getRange(row,9,1,14).clearContent();
  }
}
```